# Queries in Dynamodb

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have an application written in Nodejs that needs to find ONE row based on a city name (this could just be the table's name, different cities will be categorized as different tables), and a field named "currentJobLoads" which is a number. For example, a user might want to find ONE row with the city name "Chicago" and the lowest currentJobLoads. How can I achieve this in Dynamodb without scan operations(since scan would be slower and can only read so much data before it gets terminated)? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what your current partition key and sort key for the table are, but I'm guessing the `currentJobLoads` field isn't one of them. So you would need to create a [Global Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on the `currentJobLoads` field, at which point you will be able to run query operations against that field.

Comment: Can I use a token string for primary key to define each row and use currentJobLoads as a sort key? Will this allow me do the above query?